Problems with node version
I'm facing some problems with my node version on my pc, when i try to run a NEXT app on my vscode, it informs me that my version is on 16.20.2 (https://i.sstatic.net/GPSmiJCQ.png)
But when i go to my cmd and type "node -v" it informs that is in 21.2.0 (https://i.sstatic.net/M6rUHdwp.png)
I've already uninstalled node and installed again, but nothing changes
Please, can someone help me? I'm stuck on my NEXT studies because i can't run any projects because of this version issue
Thanks!
I tried NVM for windows, but when i type "nvm install lts" it gives me this return (https://i.sstatic.net/pzB0DvCf.png)
My guess is, my user folder on my pc has the letter "ã" because of my name (João, thats a brazilian name) and when i type nvm command it changes for a "?", is this the reason why i can't use nvm?

How did you install nvm-windows? Also, your Node version in Powershell is the one at 16 while the one in CMD is 21, they're different shells so they may be getting their environments differently.
